# How can I revert changes to a record in Oracle Forms 6i?

Tags: oracle, triggers, plsql, oracleforms

I have a form running in Oracle Forms 6i which has tabular formatted rows that are being populated from a certain table in the database. One column has a [List_Of_Values] property enabled to allow the user to select among possible values.

Some values among the list can only be selected if the user has permission to do that, and I have created a [ WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM ] trigger to check the permission after the value has been changed. The trigger raises a form_trigger_failure to prevent the user from saving the changes done.

The problem is that if the user gets notified about lack of permission to select the value, then there is no way for the user to know the previous (old) value to select it again, unless the form is cancelled which will cause his other (valid) changes to be lost too.

Here is the code I have written in the trigger

```
DECLARE
NEW_LOCATION  VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
NEW_LOCATION := :BLK_MAT_STG_PLACES_PILE.STG_LOC_ID;

    IF NEW_LOCATION LIKE 'OH01%' THEN
        IF NOT :GLOBAL.USER_ID LIKE 'Admin%' THEN
            MESSAGEBOX('You are not authorized to select this value');

            /* What can I write to load the old value to this item? */ 
            RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

I have tried ROLLBACK but that did not revert the old value to the form. I tried SYNCHRONIZE as well, but that had no effect. Is there any option other than going through the database table again to pull out the value?

Comment: I made a mistake in the IF THEN condition, I corrected it. Still waiting for the answer.

Comment: Just check if you can use global variable to preserve the value

Comment: @psaraj12 I did check that and that is how I was able to solve this problem. Check my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BEGIN    
    IF NEW_LOCATION LIKE 'OH01%' THEN
        IF NOT :GLOBAL.USER_ID LIKE 'Admin%' THEN
            MESSAGEBOX('You are not authorized to select this value');

            /* Return it to the original value that was fetched from database */ 
            :BLK_MAT_STG_PLACES_PILE.STG_LOC_ID :=
              get_item_property('BLK_MAT_STG_PLACES_PILE.STG_LOC_ID'
                               ,DATABASE_VALUE);

            RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but that did not work. It did not even trigger an error. I think Forms 6i just ignored the message.

Comment: I should have added RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;

Comment: +1 Using the DATABASE_VALUE item property would be my first preference for solving this sort of problem.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp that would work if only select a value from the [List_of_Values] will not store it directly to the database before displaying it on the form. So retrieving the database value will only retrieve the value selected by the user, not the one that was in the database before running the form.

Comment: No, DATABASE_VALUE is the value of the item when the row was queried from the database. It won't be the value "selected by the user". Anyway, you told @jva "that did work" - so if you got it working, I suggest you present your solution here.

Comment: My mistake. I was using DATABASE_VALUE in some item, but was testing in another item. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

One of my colleagues found the solution to this problem as follows:

1. Define a Global Parameter in the parameter list (I named it `TEMP_LOCATION`)
2. In the `PRE-TEXT-ITEM` trigger (which is executed before navigating to the item) I wrote

   BEGIN
   :GLOBAL.TEMP_LOCATION := :BLK_MAT_STG_PLACES_PILE.STG_LOC_ID;
   END;

3  Then in the `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` trigger code that I wrote in this question, I cancelled raising `FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE` and simply filled the item with the `TEMP_LOCATION`

```
DECLARE
    NEW_LOC  VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
        NEW_LOC := :BLK_MAT_STG_PLACES_PILE.STG_LOC_ID;

        IF   NEW_LOC LIKE 'OH01%' THEN

            IF NOT :GLOBAL.USER_ID LIKE 'Admin_%' THEN

                MESSAGE('YOU ARE NOT AUTHORIZED TO SELECT THIS VALUE');

                :BLK_MAT_STG_PLACES_PILE.STG_LOC_ID := :GLOBAL.TEMP_LOCATION;  
                  /* this solved my problem */

            END IF;

        END IF;
END;
```

I thank all of those who tried to help. If someone comes up with a better answer than my own, then I will happily accept it.